# Regex to catch all cases

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following stringified javascript-snippet that I would like to capture each case using regex

```
// case 1
let something = 1
something++

// case 2
const somethingElse = 2
const x = somethingElse + 10 // whatever

// case 3
enter code here
```

Cases keep going infinitely.. so I am looking for a regex that captures each case with all belonging code up until the next case is reached.

example of the first match should be

```
// case 1
let something = 1
something++
```

The best I could get is the following, but it always disregard the last case

```
([\/]{2}[\s]*?case[\s\S]+?(?=[\/]{2}))
```

Obviously, the Lookahead is the reason, I had other forms of regex but couldn't get a bulletproof regex..

Note: all cases should be identified consistently. The example above is using a simple pattern `case [digit]`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Unclear to what your goal is, could you try giving more depth into exactly what you're trying to do and give us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple alternation in your look ahead:

```
/([\/]{2}[\s]*?case[\s\S]+?(?=[\/]{2}|$))/gi
```

I just added `|$` in the look ahead, which means: `OR end of text`

So it will look ahead for `/` or end of text.

Comment: It still does not cover the entire case.. https://regex101.com/r/HmvorL/1

Comment: How about telling us, what it doesn't cover?

Comment: Sure, did you try the link I posted in the comment? it covers mainly the comment, instead I wanted that + all snippet that belongs to every case.

Comment: Ok, didn't see the link, sorry. Well, just remove the multiline option (the `m`). Then it works. That's because, when you use `m`, `$` changes to mean 'end of line' instead of 'end of text'.